# May a creature declare an attack while it is exhausted?

Tags: berserk-war-of-the-realms

In Berserk: War of the Realms, if a creature 'may declare a magical strike' on some condition, does that apply even when it is exhausted? For example, the Elf Spellslinger 'may declare a magical strike' if an adjacent creature of the opponent becomes exhausted. Is he allowed to use that even when he himself is exhausted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [post on BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/14027782) abilities can be declared even if a creature is exhausted.